# Discount codes on itunesconnect for any other purchase than auto renewable

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, discount, promotion-code

I am confused with Apples discount/promo code possibilities inside itunes connect.

while auto renewable subscriptions have the possibilities of creating

- Introductory offer
- Promotial offer
- Offer codes

(inapp purchases -> manage)

I can't find such a thing for any other purchase type Apple offers. Is it really the case that such kind of offers are only possible for auto renewable subscriptions and not for any other purchase type?

Thanks for the help
Andreas

Comment: These are only available for auto renewing subscription. For other purchase types you can simply create an IAP with the desired, lower price, and provide some way for the user to purchase that item in your app under the desired conditions.  This technique doesn't work for auto renewing subs since the user can see all subscription products in system settings when they manage their subs, so they could just choose the cheaper one.

Comment: @Paulw11 alright, thanks a lot for the help